# Swift UIViewController subclass instance variable initialization strategy

Tags: ios, swift, option-type, instance-variables, unwrap

I have several UIViewController subclasses which need some instance data set before they can load properly.

For Example: - Note: This is a contrived example so apologies if I've missed some minor details - line 2 is the only part really necessary for the question.

```
class VehicleSpecificationsTableViewController: UITableViewController {
  var vehicle: Vehicle! // <-- Implicitly unwrapped optional is my current solution

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return vehicle.specs.count // <-- Crashes here if the view ever loads/reloads when I'm not expecting it
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("vehicleSpecCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? VehicleSpecTableViewCell
    cell.spec = vehicle.specs[indexPath.row]
    return cell
  }
}
```

The question is what type of variable should be used here as a best practice. I have been using optionals, but it's a pain having to unwrap them everywhere, so I'm converting to implicitly unwrapped optionals since I will be setting the variable before the view is loaded in general.

The problem is I'm worried about the controller getting reloaded at times when I'm not directly aware of it (after a memory warning, device rotation, awake from background, any other strange edge case). While I know this probably *shouldn't* happen, it still just seems really dangerous using an implicitly unwrapped optional if I'm not 100% sure that it's impossible for it to be nil at all times. So I'm thinking of placing a check somewhere to ensure that any implicitly unwrapped variables are actually set before load.

**EDIT**: A more likely scenario of it being nil is a second developer coming along in a few months and implementing something that uses my controller, and isn't aware that the instance variable needs to be set before it loads. While they should know better I suppose, it would result in a crash in production and that's what I'm trying to avoid. I want it to be impossible for it to crash without relying on convention (and hopefully not checking/unwrapping optionals in many/all functions)

So far I've found that putting the check in the viewDidLoad() is too late. I've tried putting it in viewWillAppear() but that doesn't work for things like UITableViewControllers because they attempt to load their data before the view attempts to appear.

**Basic question is**, has the Swift community decided on a best practice here? Does one use optionals and deal with unwrapping, implicitly unwrapped optionals and deal with nil checks in strategic places, non-optionals and add init() to each controller? Or is there a better solution I just haven't come across yet?

Any thoughts/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I use implicitly unwrapped optionals and testing. You could check an optional for nil, but what are you going to do?  Your app probably can't continue if it is suddenly nil.  You can log some sort of error message but an exception during testing/development is more useful. Your view controller can't be reloaded unless your whole app is restarted. iOS can send you a low memory warning but won't arbitrarily remove things from memory unless it kills your entire app; and will only happen while your app is suspended

Comment: In many cases the controller in question has been segued to and is on top of a navigation controller stack, so the recovery for it being nil is to show an alert to the user that something went wrong, and then pop the controller off the stack. It doesn't fix whatever problem caused it to get into a nil state, but it doesn't crash which is the most important thing.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of an implicitly unwrapped optional is fine, and just because you are using implicitly unwrapped optionals there is nothing to stop you from checking to see if the optional is nil before you use it.

Set a guard statement at the top of your functions to exit early if the variable is nil.

Comment: But that requires setting a guard statement in every function... in which case I might as well use the same guard statement to unwrap an optional. I was hoping for a best-practice of maybe one or two places where it needs to be guarded against and then I don't have to worry about it from then on.

Comment: Where does the vehicle come from within the view controller?  What does it mean for the view controller to exist without the vehicle?  If the view controller does not make any sense at all without the vehicle then you should probably set it up so that the vehicle is passed to construct the view controller.  If it makes sense to have the view controller without a vehicle then you should be explicitly handling the case when it's not there.

Comment: The view controller has no place existing without the vehicle. So I agree the (hopefully rare) case where it could be nil needs to be explicitly handled... hence the purpose of the question in the first place: What is the best practice the Swift community has adopted for this situation? I know I can make it optional and check it everywhere, but it's a huge pain to do so and I'm guessing someone has come up with a better pattern.

Comment: The implicitly unwrapped optional *is* the better pattern.  If you wanted to check somewhere, then I would suggest `viewWillAppear`, since if it doesn't have a value at this point, you probably aren't going to be able to display things properly, but this is a result of a bug - you didn't set things up properly in `prepareForSegue` as an example. In which case a crash will show you exactly what is going on during testing, let you fix the bug and move on

Comment: Yeah, I've thought about putting a nil check in `viewWillAppear`, but it's not the first delegate that gets called in some situations (such as UITableViewControllers). In those cases the first thing called seems to be `tableView: numberOfRowsInSection`. I may just put the check in both places for in that case and call it a day. Was just hoping for a better solution.